# Binding multiple CSV documents and assigning to variable

Tags: r

I'm able to bind multiple CSVs

```
list.files(path = "/Users/path file",
           pattern="*.csv", 
           full.names = T) %>% 
   map_df(~read_csv(.))
```

but as soon as I try to assign it to a variable so I can delete some columns, it tells me there is an error

```
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

source('~/.active-rstudio-document', echo=TRUE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
list.files(path = "/Users/path file",
           pattern="*.csv", 
           full.names = T) %>% 
   abc <- map_df(~read_csv(.))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment should be either at the start as the `%>%` is connecting both each of the statements together

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
 abc <- list.files(path = "/Users/path file",
       pattern="*.csv", 
       full.names = TRUE) %>% 
     map_df(~read_csv(.))
```

---

Or at the end

```
list.files(path = "/Users/path file",
       pattern="*.csv", 
       full.names = TRUE) %>% 
     map_df(~read_csv(.)) -> abc
```

---

i.e. there is no break unless we break the chain `%>%` and create new objects

```
tmp <- list.files(path = "/Users/path file",
       pattern="*.csv", 
       full.names = TRUE) 
abc <- map_df(tmp, ~read_csv(.))
```